# Cloudfront in front of Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a java application running on tomcat that deployed on beanstalk. I'm not finding much information out there on this topic, so I'm wondering if someone could tell me the pros and cons to using cloudfront in front of beanstalk. I understand it makes sense with an s3 bucket, but I'm not clear on EBS. One benifit I see is it's ability to automatically handle http to https redirection without the need to setup a rewriter on the ec2 instance, however I'm not sure the extra cost is worth that. If anybody knows anything about this, I'd really like to know.

Comment: This sounds too broad for stackoverflow. However one thing you need to think about it how cachable your content. If it is, using CloudFront can significantly reduce load on your back-end application

Comment: This is a Q&A site right? How does it know to take the load off the back-end application. My site is an automotive classified site, I'm assuming the listings are cachable, but the searches aren't? I don't really know much about this which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at CF's manual introductory section: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html (see section How CloudFront Delivers Content to Your Users). And you are right - usually static assets (e.g images) are cacheable, and dynamic (e.g. search results) are not, but it really depends on your application.